# How to use vue3-simple-alert in Vue

Tags: vuejs3, alert

This is the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-simple-alert). I am doing what they show.

```
main.js

import VueSimpleAlert from 'vue3-simple-alert'

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(VueSimpleAlert);
app.mount('#app');
```

And in my component I use this inside a function in my `methods:`

```
this.$alert("Hello");
```

The problem is that I get an error in the console

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.$alert is not a function
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably it's not prepared for the **app.use**. Did you try this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueSimpleAlert from "vue-simple-alert";

Vue.use(VueSimpleAlert);
```

Or you can use the [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) I saw the github repository of **VueSimpleAlert** the latest commit is from 3 years ago.

Comment: SweetAlert2 works fine. Thanks. I'm not sure if I should mark your comment as an answer.